# Jscrollpane isn't scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Here's the code I have for my GUI

```
public class gui extends JFrame{

JFrame mainF;
JPanel listPanel;
JTextArea jtArea;
ButtonGroup buttons;
ButtonGroup restoreButtons;
JRadioButton createButton;
JRadioButton saveButton;
JRadioButton deleteButton;
JRadioButton redo;
JRadioButton undo;

gui() {

    this.mainF = new JFrame();
    mainF.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
    mainF.setLayout(null); 
    mainF.setSize(800, 800);

    createButton = new JRadioButton("Create note");
    createButton.setBounds(10, 150, 150, 50);

    saveButton = new JRadioButton("Save note");
    saveButton.setBounds(10, 250, 150, 50);
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);




    redo = new JRadioButton("Redo");
    redo.setBounds(10, 400, 150, 50);
    redo.setEnabled(false);

    undo = new JRadioButton("Undo");
    undo.setBounds(10, 350, 150, 50);
    undo.setEnabled(false);

    deleteButton = new JRadioButton("Delete note");
    deleteButton.setBounds(10, 500, 150, 50);
    deleteButton.setEnabled(false);

    this.jtArea = new JTextArea();
    int centerX = (mainF.getWidth() - 200) / 2;
    int centerY = (mainF.getHeight() - 500) / 2;
    jtArea.setBounds(centerX, centerY, 200, 500);
    jtArea.setBackground(Color.white);
    jtArea.setEnabled(false);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtArea);
    scrollPane.setBounds(centerX, centerY, 200, 500); 
    jtArea.setLineWrap(true); 
    jtArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); 
    jtArea.setEnabled(false);


    this.listPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(listPanel);
    listScrollPane.setBounds(centerX + 285, centerY, 200, 500);
    listScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    
    buttons = new ButtonGroup();
    buttons.add(createButton);
    buttons.add(saveButton);
    buttons.add(deleteButton);
    buttons.add(undo);
    buttons.add(redo);


    mainF.add(jtArea);
    mainF.add(createButton);
    mainF.add(saveButton);
    mainF.add(deleteButton);
    mainF.add(redo);
    mainF.add(undo);
    mainF.add(listScrollPane);
    mainF.setVisible(true); 
    mainF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I'm still unfamiliar with GUI components so this is very new to me. It shows a scroll bar on the right side, but I can't scroll through it when it's full. My entire code is supposed to add buttons to that listPanel and if it gets full then I can scroll through them but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `mainF.setLayout(null); ` is a bad idea - [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2F/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: `jtArea.setBounds(centerX, centerY, 200, 500);` this isn't helping you either. You're fixing the size of the JTextArea so that it cannot expand if need be.

Comment: do you mean scrolling of `listPanel`? In *posted* code, it is empty, so there is nothing to scroll! You posted a lot of (irrelevant?) code but somehow the post is missing almost all code regarding `listPanel` (assuming that is the one not scorlling) - if I add enough buttons to it, I can scroll normally.

Comment: @MadProgrammer but I want to be able to manually set the location of all my components. Why do you advise against it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But I don't want it to expand, but rather be able to scroll through it. If that can still be done without a fixed size, how can I set the default size?

Comment: 1) There is absolutely no reason to manually set the location of components. Swing was designed be used with layout managers. In fact, scrolling won't work when you use a null layout. 2) See: user85421's comment about not having any components on the panel. If there are no components there is not reason to scroll. 3) Swing components can only have a single parent. Your text area won't scroll either. First you add the text area to a scroll pane. But then you remove the text area from the scroll pane when you add it to the frame. You need to add the scroll pane to the frame, not the text area.

Comment: maybe the problem is adding components to an already displayed container without revalidating the layout, as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) for `add()`: "This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component."

Comment: Also: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. 2) You should NOT extend JFrame since you are not adding functionality to the frame. The tutorial has many examples for basic Swing coding.

Comment: “…but I want to be able to manually set the location of all my components.” How many pixels do you think your JRadioButton’s font will need on other computers? Characters in a “12 point” font are *not* 12 pixels high; they are ¹²⁄₇₂ inch high, and the number of pixels needed depends on the dot pitch of the monitor. And you can’t even be certain other users will have the same system font at all. If all this sounds complicated… well, that’s why you need to let Swing components compute their own preferred sizes, and you need to use a layout manager so those sizes are respected.

Comment: @JosephE *"but I want to be able to manually set the location of all my components. Why do you advise against it?"* - Well, for the reasons you've just discovered, as well as the fact that font metrics, DPI and other platform settings WILL change the amount of space components need - the layout management system was designed to help solve those issues and make creating complex interfaces faster, simpler, easier and more robust.  Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion and have been ever since we started moving away from text based terminals.

Comment: I had to add a main method but I finally saw your GUI.  None of the buttons work except the Create Note button.  I can't write in either note area.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Study the rest of the tutorial.  Your approach to Swing is totally, absolutely wrong and unfixable.

Comment: I have the impression that nobody is really understanding the problem... better add a [mre] - **minimal**: remove unnecessary code (components); **reproducible**: shows the problem, in your case: how the buttons are added to the `listPanel` - otherwise it will be hard to get an answer that is not just some guess

Answer (score 1):

`mainF.setLayout(null);` is your first mistake.

```
public class gui extends JFrame {
    JFrame mainF;
```

is your second.  Which `JFrame` are you actually using?!  As a general rule avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`, you're not adding any additional functionally to the class and `JFrame` is a complex compound component, best to just avoid it.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtArea);
//...
mainF.add(jtArea);
```

is your third mistake (credit to camickr) - you're applying the `JTextArea` to the `JScrollPane`, which is correct, but then adding the `JTextArea` to the `JFrame`, which will first remove it from the `JScrollPane` ... and now the `JScrollPane` isn't even been displayed.  You should be adding the `scrollPane` to the frame, not the `JTextArea`.

Remember, you're not stuck to using a single layout manager, you can make use of multiple layout managers through a process of "compound layouts", for example...

[image]

*Please note - the above screen shot shows preloaded text, which is not present in the example code*

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GUI());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GUI extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea jtArea;
        private ButtonGroup buttons;
        private JRadioButton createButton;
        private JRadioButton saveButton;
        private JRadioButton deleteButton;
        private JRadioButton redo;
        private JRadioButton undo;
        private JPanel listPanel;

        GUI() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

            // Not sure why you'd use radio buttons for this, but your problem
            createButton = new JRadioButton("Create note");

            saveButton = new JRadioButton("Save note");
            saveButton.setEnabled(false);

            redo = new JRadioButton("Redo");
            redo.setEnabled(false);

            undo = new JRadioButton("Undo");
            undo.setEnabled(false);

            deleteButton = new JRadioButton("Delete note");
            deleteButton.setEnabled(false);

            buttons = new ButtonGroup();
            buttons.add(createButton);
            buttons.add(saveButton);
            buttons.add(deleteButton);
            buttons.add(undo);
            buttons.add(redo);

            actionsPane.add(createButton);
            actionsPane.add(saveButton);
            actionsPane.add(redo);
            actionsPane.add(undo);
            actionsPane.add(deleteButton);

            this.jtArea = new JTextArea();
            // This provides a sizing hint for how wide the text area should be
            jtArea.setColumns(80);

            jtArea.setLineWrap(true);
            jtArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            //jtArea.setEnabled(false);

            // Just as a FYI, I'd probably consider using a JList for this
            this.listPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                listPanel.add(new JLabel("Note " + (index + 1)));
            }

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtArea);
            JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(listPanel);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

            add(actionsPane, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0.5;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            add(scrollPane, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            // If there is nothing in the listPanel, this will collapse to a 
            // 0 width, which is why I'd recommend using JList instead
            add(listScrollPane, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend taking a look at:

- [Coding Conventions for the Java Language](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)
- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2F/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/textarea.html)
- [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/list.html)